# LinuxDC++ not closing

Tags: command-line

I have Ubuntu gnome-desktop 16.04 installed in my laptop. The file-sharing network software Linuxdc++(linuxdcpp) is not closing properly in my machine. It started a week ago. When I open it all my audio sources stop working and all web players are freezing. Even after I close my system is getting slow and hangs after certain time. I checked `ps aufx | grep linuxdcpp` and `top | linuxdcpp` and found the problem. It is still running in the background.

Screenshot of top command's output:

[image]

After I kill this everything seems to be working normal. But I am sick of doing this everytime. Can someone suggest an alternate idea

P.S : I have tried other versions of dc++ in ubuntu but I really like Linuxdc++ so any help that doesn't include getting rid of linuxdcpp will be grateful.

Comment: Could you try start it from command line and see if there will be  any error message if you try to close it. [edit] question and add output of `linuxdcpp --version` in addition to how did you install it?